# Having trouble formulating how this footer could be done with css... screenshot attached

Tags: css, layout, css-position, transparent

I am usually pretty good at css stuff, but I'm stumped by this one.

Here's a screenshot of the footer I am working with - I already have everything else set up correct.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhFGd.jpg

So, I can put that image as an imgtag I think, and that way it has the transparency for the other image in the background.

However, the thing I'm stumped on, is how do I get the full width gradient to extend on both the right and left sides of the image?  Does anyone have any tips of how I can do that? Basically having the transparency show through, but the gradient extend on both sides of the div so that it goes full width?

Please let me know if I'm unclear or if there's something I need to explain better.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen of your code for us to better understand?

Comment: hmm it's on my local host, I'll post later tonight...

Comment: Although, I think what might work is a 3 column layout, the ones on the right / left are just floated with the one in the middle being pretty wide.  That one in the middle can have the img tag, footer info below it, and the columns next to it can have the same class / gradient.  That will work I think....

Comment: I ended up getting this to work by just having the three col with background images like I was originally thinking... nothing too crazy. If anyone sees this thread and needs help, hit me up :)